# How can I create a shortcut for the start menu to launch an application?

Tags: eclipse, .desktop

Some apps I've installed, like Eclipse IDE, can be launched from an icon on the desktop, but I would like to have it available in the start menu.

I should be able to go to the start menu and click on the application and have it launch exactly the same way as launching it from the desktop/folder.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Seconding what @pomsky said. And in case you are at all confused, the launchers in Ubuntu are just a special kind of executable text file that have `.desktop` at the end and are structured in a certain way. Opening them executes a command that launches the application. The folder he referenced is where all the "dock" or "start menu" launchers live.

Comment: I know that, but what I didn't know was where the folder was, I didn't ask just for the location because maybe there is an easier way to do it.

Comment: @YoureSOStubborn See my expanded answer, try `alacarte` for a GUI alternative.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a launcher in your desktop, then copy/move the launcher from your desktop to the `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. It should appear in the menu.

Otherwise, you may manually create a simple `.desktop` launcher (say `eclipse.desktop`) in your `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. The content of the `eclipse.desktop` may be as follows.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/full/path/to/the/executable
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/the/icon-file
```

For a GUI alternative, try Main Menu (aka Alacarte). You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

Comment: It does work in a way but, I had to make a `.desktop` configuration for it to work

Comment: be sure to check in `/usr/share/applications/` if you are looking for one that already exists